# Code compiling on gcc, but not on msvc

Tags: c++, templates, g++, visual-c++-2010, visual-studio-2010

I have a problem compiling a template using msvc-2010. It works perfectly using gcc 4.6.3.

I have boiled down the code to the essential (it doesn't make sense of course):

```
//Variant that works
template <typename T, T* Ptr>
void callFun()
{
}

//Traits class (type expands to the same type T* as above)
template <typename T>
class TraitsClass
{
public:
    typedef T* type;
};

//Essentially the same as callFun2, only that the
//type of Ptr is expressed indirectly over a traits class
//The usage of this class is not possible, because of the error described below
template <typename T, typename TraitsClass<T>::type Ptr>
void callFun2()
{
}

//Provides a compile constant ptr for this example
void testFun()
{
}

int main()
{
    //Works
    callFun<void(), &testFun>();

    //Fails
    callFun2<void(), &testFun>();

    //Works
    callFun2<void(), 0>();

    return 0;
}
```

The Error:

```
error C2975: 'Ptr' : invalid template argument for 'callFun2', expected compile-time constant expression
```

I find it interesting, that it only fails when the second type parameter is being used through a typedef in a Traits class.
g++ compiles this example correctly without warnings, even when using -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic (Except for the unused parameters, of course)

Thank you very much.

Comment: My guess would be that MSVC expects that `typename` introduces a type argument, but here `Ptr` is a non-type argument. Don't have the syntax for template arguments handy, though.

Comment: Good idea, but unfortunately it does not seem to have anything to do with that. There is an error that even suggests that the typename keyword should be used. This does make sense to me, because T* is really a type.

Comment: I'll make it even worse: this does not work either:
//Variant that works
template <typename T, T* Ptr>
void callFun()
{
 callFun2<T, Ptr>();
}

Answer (score 2):

Well, I think that the answer is that compilers are not written by gods. Programming standards in the compiler industry are extremely high, MS C++ is a good compiler, but it still contain bugs. I came across the following, that is somehow similar to what you are pointing at:

```
template <class item_struct>
struct THeapBasedArray
{
    void  Sort(int (__cdecl *compareFunction)(const item_struct *item1,
                                              const item_struct *item2));
};

struct Item { int x; };

struct ItemPtrsArray : public THeapBasedArray<Item*>
{
    static int __cdecl  Compare1(const Item **pp1, const Item **pp2);

    typedef Item *ItemPtr;
    static int __cdecl  Compare2(const ItemPtr *pp1, const ItemPtr *pp2);
};

int main()
{
    ItemPtrsArray vect;

    vect.Sort(ItemPtrsArray::Compare1);
    vect.Sort(ItemPtrsArray::Compare2);
}
```

The first call to Sort fails with:

> > cpptest1.cxx(21) : error C2664: 'THeapBasedArray::Sort' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int (_*cdecl *)(const Item **, const Item **)' to 'int (*_cdecl *)(const item_struct *, const item_struct *)

while the second call compilers fine. For me this is a bug in a compiler. Sometimes this happens. I guess this is the answer.

Comment: I don't think, that this example has anything to do with my problem. I would expect every compiler to give an error like that one you posted. Or have I overseen something?

Comment: The compiler is correct to complain since the two functions `ItemPtrsArray::Compare1()` and `ItemPtrsArray::Compare2()` are *NOT* identical.  Herb Sutter wrote an interesting piece on this very topic in his "Conversations with a Guru" series.  http://www.drdobbs.com/conversationsa-midsummer-nights-madness/184403835  TLDR - you should never say `typedef Item *ItemPtr` precisely because it does introduce the potential errors of this sort.  Follow the advice of the great prophet Dan Saks as cited in Herb's article, and your error will become plain to you.